# Unable to find locators(Xpath,Css) ,in the webpage

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, automated-tests

I am trying to automate application,tried first to find xpath or CSS locators unable to find looks no frame also inside the element.

I am able to handle using JavaScript but unable to enter full text in the search box,it's trimming some text,,please help me.

JavaScript which i tried.

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return document.querySelector('#app').shadowRoot.querySelector('#base > wego-search-form').shadowRoot.querySelector('div > wego-hotel-search-form').shadowRoot.querySelector('#loc').shadowRoot.querySelector('#item0 > div.disable-select.city-country-name').click();");

((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return document.querySelector('#app').shadowRoot.querySelector('#base > wego-search-form').shadowRoot.querySelector('div > wego-hotel-search-form').shadowRoot.querySelector('#dates').shadowRoot.querySelector('#depart').shadowRoot.querySelector('#btn').click();");
```

My scenario i want to click search form and enter some destination details,If possible anyway i can handle this case using locators suggest me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shadow DOM Elements are used in this website. Shadow DOM provides encapsulation for the JavaScript, CSS, and templating in a Web Component.

> Shadow DOM allows hidden DOM trees to be attached to elements in the
>   regular DOM tree — this shadow DOM tree starts with a shadow root,
>   underneath which can be attached to any elements you want, in the same
>   way as the normal DOM.

Refer [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM) To get details about it or for more details Google it.

Now handle Shadow element take reference from [this blog](https://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/accessing-shadow-dom-elements-with-webdriver). I've tried the below code to enter text as you expected and its working for me.

```
public static WebDriver driver;

public static void main(String[] args){

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "driver_path");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.wego.com.my/hotels");
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    WebElement root1 = driver.findElement(By.id("app"));

    WebElement shadowRoot1 = expandRootElement(root1);

    WebElement root2 = shadowRoot1.findElement(By.tagName("wego-search-form"));
    WebElement shadowRoot2 = expandRootElement(root2);

    WebElement root3 = shadowRoot2.findElement(By.tagName("wego-hotel-search-form"));
    WebElement shadowRoot3 = expandRootElement(root3);

    WebElement root4 = shadowRoot3.findElement(By.id("loc"));
    WebElement shadowRoot4 = expandRootElement(root4);
    shadowRoot4.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.root-container div.container")).click();    

    WebElement element = shadowRoot4.findElement(By.id("searchKeywordInput"));
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    action.click(element).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "a"));
    element.sendKeys(Keys.DELETE);
    element.sendKeys("narendra");
}


public static WebElement expandRootElement(WebElement element) {
    WebElement newElement = (WebElement) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].shadowRoot", element);
    return newElement;
}
```

**Updated**

As an alternative of `sendKeys()`, `JavascriptExecutor` can be used to set the value of text box. Use below code

```
WebElement element = shadowRoot4.findElement(By.id("searchKeywordInput"));
JavascriptExecutor javascriptExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
javascriptExecutor.executeScript("arguments[0].value='Your Text Goes Here';", element);
```

I've tested this so many time and this is working fine in each case.

**Note:** using `JavascriptExecutor` may not trigger the search result auto suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for the response Narendra,Now i can able to find the element but still come to my first issue where i cannot enter full text in the search box,it's trimming while entering text

Comment: @SinuReddy, Updated the answer. Please check and let me know if still have issue.